# Auszug aus Nathan der Weise (I.1, 5-8)

Tags: meaning, grammar-identification, literature

Ich brauche Hilfe, um einen Auszug (I.1, 5-8) aus [Nathan der Weise](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nathan_der_Weise) zu verstehen. Dieses Theaterstück lese ich in der Suhrkampf BasisBibliothek Ausgabe, mit der Hilfe der französischen Übersetzung von Robert Pitrou. Ich spreche kein gut Deutsch : zögere nicht, meine Fehler zu korrigieren!

**Hier ist [der Auszug](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Lessing,+Gotthold+Ephraim/Dramen/Nathan+der+Weise/1.+Akt/1.+Auftritt) (I.1, 5-8):**

```
[...] Babylon 
Ist von Jerusalem, wie ich den Weg, 
Seit ab bald rechts, bald links, zu nehmen bin 
Genötigt worden, gut zwei hundert Meilen;
```

**So schreibe ich diesen Auszug um:**

Mit dem Weg - bald rechts, bald links -, den ich genötigt worden bin zu nehmen, ist Babylon gut zwei hundert Meilen von Jerusalem.

**Drei Fragen :**

- ist meine Lesart korrekt ?
- was bedeutet "wie" ? Funktioniert dieses Wort im Satz als Relativpronomen? (~ mit dem Weg, den ich... ?)
- was bedeutet "Seit ab" ? In meiner französischen Ausgabe steht "Seitab".

**Ihre Hilfe ist willkommen !**

---

**Hier ist der vollständige Auszug: (I.1, 5-8)**

```
Nathan:
Ja, Daja; Gott sei Dank! Doch warum endlich?
Hab' ich denn eher wiederkommen wollen?
Und wiederkommen können? Babylon
Ist von Jerusalem, wie ich den Weg,
Seit ab bald rechts, bald links, zu nehmen bin
Genötigt worden, gut zwei hundert Meilen;
Und Schulden einkassieren, ist gewiß
Auch kein Geschäft, das merklich födert, das
So von der Hand sich schlagen läßt.
```

Comment: Evtl kann wer auch sagen, welche Version von seitab/seit ab im ursprünglichen Original steht. Gedruckt findet man ja beides. [DWB](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS25491#XGS25491) zitiert sogar die Stelle unter dem Eintrag "seitab" wie hier im Zitat geschrieben und schreibt/erlaubt auch selbst "seit ab gehen". Bedeutung ist also dieselbe (um Punkt 3 vorwegzunehmen ;) )

Comment: @mtwde Das Original hat *seit ab* [Link](http://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/book/view/lessing_nathan_1779?p=9).

Comment: @DavidVogt Danke. Wohl eine Anpassung an die moderne Schreibweise, so wie eine Zeile darunter genöthigt zu genötigt wurde.

Comment: Diesen Satz zu verstehen, wäre wohl auch nicht jedem Muttersprachler ohne weiteres möglich. Er ist, der Poesie geschuldet, sehr verdreht. Wenn es Dir ums Deutschlernen geht, frage ich mich, ob nicht andere Literatur geeigneter wäre...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dieses **wie** entschuldigt im Zusammenhang mit **genötigt worden** nochmals den Umweg.

> So wie ich umständehalber gehen musste war es viel weiter.

Das ist ein impliziter Vergleich mit dem direkten Weg.

Deine Umschreibung ist zwar inhaltlich richtig – es sollte allerdings *auf dem Weg* statt *mit dem Weg* lauten –, unterschlägt jedoch die Entschuldigung.

Diese impliziten Vergleiche kommen im Deutschen recht häufig vor:

> Ich mache es so. Ich mache es richtig.
>
> So wie ich es mache, ist es richtig.

Im obigen Beispiel dient der Vergleich mit der nicht ausgesprochenen Hypothese, es anders zu machen, einer Verstärkung der Behauptung, das eigene Tun sei richtig.

Comment: Ich denke entschuldigt ist hier das falsche Wort. Er begründet eher den Umweg., wenn man bedenkt, dass er hier mit seiner Haushälterin/Angestellten spricht.

Comment: Erstmal sind Hausangestellte echte Besen. Und vielleicht ist das ja ein Fingerzeig darauf, dass er was mit ihr hatte?